# Inno Setup installer defaults to Custom install instead of Full

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Installer defaults to the *Custom install* instead of the *Full* no matter what. In case that there is no solution for that, can I have checked all the components by default in custom install?

Comment: What is the order in `[Types]` Section? Have you installed your app earlier? If so, setup may select previous setting [UsePreviousSetupType](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_useprevioussetuptype) as default.

Comment: @RobeN You had right. It was a previous install. Solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed your application earlier using your setup script and now you are reinstalling, it may be that Setup uses **previous type** as default.

Please check [`UsePreviousSetupType`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_useprevioussetuptype) parameter for `[Setup]` Section.